# Return an empty object of a certain type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
justExpose :: Maybe a -> a
justExpose (Just x) = x
justExpose Nothing = -- an empty object of type a
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty object"? (What do you think is the purpose of `Maybe`?)

Comment: Well, just to conform to the type declaration. A maybe means there could be something or nothing, for safety's sake, right?

Comment: The only possibility is ⊥ a.k.a. `undefined`. You cannot conjure up an `a` without further constraints.

Comment: There is no such a thing as an "empty object" in Haskell. A function `Maybe a -> a` is inherently partial. The best you can do is return `error "justExpose Nothing"`. Still, partial functions such as these should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Bottom line, I think you should keep the `Maybe` as it is when you're working with `Maybe` values -- they got to be a `Maybe` for a reason after all. If you really want to use this (unsafe) operation, you can use `Data.Maybe`'s `fromJust`. You can also see how it's defined in the Haddock documentation.

Comment: @qed - Welcome to [haskell]; this looks like your first question here. I think this is a good question; it's short, to the point, and has a variety of helpful answers. Regarding your "for safety's sake" comment: Haskell and Haskell programmers are really, really serious about "type safety." Generally, we like to think that non-safe operations (like your `justExpose`) as *inexpressible* in the language, without resorting to `undefined`, `error`, etc.

Comment: @ChristianConkle, thanks for your help. This journey into haskell is very enjoyable so far, I think I will find enlightenment and liberation at some point.

Comment: Oh, and a little more jargon translation: a "partial" function, as @chi called it, is more or less a function that might not terminate, i.e. might crash. (`undefined` is notionally an infinite loop, `undefined = undefined`, but in practice *evaluating* `undefined` immediately raises an exception.) The antonym is a "total" function.

Comment: I don't think there is a thing like "empty `Integer`". That's not how things are done in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Maybe a` **is** the standard "type with empty value".

The way to extract that `a` is to perform a case-split or (better) use a

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a  -- Defined in ‘Data.Maybe’
```

function, which is declared as

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe def optional = 
    case optional of
        Just value -> value
        Nothing    -> def
```

So, you just need to `import Data.Maybe` and call `fromMaybe` with an appropriate "empty object" of your choice (or what the task's domain requires there).

You can also leave it as `Maybe a` or even start to work in the `Maybe` monad, if you have many `a -> Maybe b` actions in the domain; the question here is the reason behind your "How do I...".

Comment: I think this is brilliant, a little reminiscent of python's defaultdict.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to define a generic version of this that works on all higher kinded types, like `[]`, `Either`, `Maybe` and so on

Answer (score 10):

In case your type `a` has monoid structure in it, then you can use this:

```
import Data.Monoid

justExpose :: Monoid a => Maybe a -> a
justExpose (Just x) = x
justExpose Nothing = mempty
```

Some examples of this:

```
λ> let x = Nothing :: Maybe (Sum Int)
λ> justExpose x
Sum {getSum = 0}
λ> justExpose (Just [])
[]
```

But you should note that `Maybe` type is very useful in lots of situations.

Comment: To elaborate: The constraint `Monoid a =>` expresses, among other things, the idea that there is a meaningful "empty value" of type `a`, namely `mempty`. As other answers point out, Haskell does not in general have a concept of an "empty value", but some types (`[a]`, `Maybe a`, `Sum Int`) do have such a value (`[]`, `Nothing`, and `Sum 0` respectively).

Comment: Oh, and it's not immediately obvious, but `justExpose` is available in `base` (but not the `Prelude`) in the guise of [`Data.Foldable.fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is a "null" in many other languages. Haskell deliberately does not provide such a thing, because it is unsafe.

You *can* get the code to compile as follows:

```
justExpose :: Maybe a -> a
justExpose (Just x) = x
justExpose Nothing = undefined
```

but if you call it with a `Nothing` you will get a runtime exception, because the value is, as the name suggests, undefined!

**Update**: As several people have pointed out, this functionality is provided by `Data.Maybe.fromJust`, as you can find by searching [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe%20a%20-%3E%20a) for your type signature `Maybe a -> a`

Comment: It might be worth noting that this function is then identical to `Data.Maybe.fromJust`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that using functions like `fromJust`/`justExpose` (or `undefined`) is kind of a hack. It's a great way to abandon Haskell's supposed "if it compiles, it works" quality.

Comment: BTW, if the purpose of this is only "I don't want to worry about the `Nothing` case right now", then instead of explicitly stating `justExpose Nothing = undefined` (or using `fromJust`), it's in some senses better to leave out that clause entirely and define _only_ `Just x -> x`. This will then give you a much more descriptive error when it does fail (`Foo.hs:123:4-56: Non-exhaustive patterns` rather than `*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`), and also a `-Wall` compiler warning.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an "empty object of a certain type" in Haskell (the gruesome "null" from various other languages).  This is [a necessity for type safety](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3186).  If you ever want an "empty value" you are required to use `Maybe`.

There is however a thing known as `⊥` ("bottom"), which in some ways similar but not really the same thing.  Every type has `⊥` as a possible value.  Bottom manifests itself in several ways: typically as an error or as an infinite loop.  For example, the following function yields bottom:

```
f x = f (x + 1)
```

This function will never return because it will loop indefinitely, and hence it's value is `⊥`.  Or you can raise an `error`:

```
justExpose :: Maybe a -> a
justExpose Nothing = error "there is Nothing"
```

But keep in mind such an error *cannot be caught*!*  The `error` function (or similarly, the `undefined` value) should only be used when you know that it's *not supposed to ever happen*.  (As a side note: the `justExpose` function is already available in the [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Maybe.html) module in the form of [`fromJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust).)

[*] There are some tricks involving `IO` that can be used to catch it, but it can't be done in pure code without `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: What's "unreliable" about catching exceptions?

Comment: I recall reading somewhere about the possibility of `error` to avoid getting caught due to compiler optimizations, but since I can't find the source to back this up I'll leave it out since it's probably wrong.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you're saying. Such optimization exist, but I don't know if they're enabled by default.